# How do I call presentViewController from an OpenGLES based app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I'm using the GLSprite base code.  I have a EAGLAppDelegate and an EAGLView.  I tried adding a navController variable to the delegate:

```
// AppDelegate.h
@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *navController;
// AppDelegate.m
@synthesize navController = _navController;
```

and then doing the following in touchesBegan (for testing), but navController is NULL and nothing appears?  How can I fix this?

```
GLSpriteAppDelegate *ad = (GLSpriteAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

SLComposeViewController *fbController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler __block completionHandler=^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
    [fbController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    switch(result){
        case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
        default:
            NSLog(@"Cancelled.....");
            break;
        case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
            NSLog(@"Posted....");
            break;
    }};
//[fbController addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"]];
[fbController setInitialText:@"Test message"];
[fbController addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.test.com"]];
[fbController setCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
[ad.navController presentViewController:fbController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: did you create `navController`?

Comment: You don't seem to be alloc-initing your nav controller anywhere.

Comment: I thought @synthesize navController = _navController; was copying the base class variable to a local one or something, I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to add a variable, you have to put something inside...

Your navigation controller (`navController`) is `nil` because you did not assign anything to it. Also note that if you want the controller to appear, the navigation controller has to be on the screen.

Usually, you should present a controller from the current controller. If you architecture your classes correctly, you have the code for presenting controller inside a controller class. However, you can always access the window root controller by

```
[ad.window.rootViewController presentViewController:...]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I used ad.window.rootViewController and it doesn't crash, but it also doesn't do anything, the value of ad.window.rootViewController is valid.  This is on iOS 6.1 Simulator.  If my game is displaying then I'm assuming the ad.window.rootViewController is on the screen?  Is there a return value I should be checking, how should I proceed?